# How to know which theme are we using in wordpress and change the content as well?

Tags: themes

I am working on a website (built on wordpress, not sure which theme are we using) in which I want to edit the content of it.

After log-in inside the website for the same homepage, I see the following screenshot but don't see anything in the screenshot where I can edit the content of a website.

I have worked on wordpress divi theme before where everything comes up after login but I am not seeing anything below here.

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering where I have to go in order to edit the content of the [site](http://test.caubo.ca/) Not finding anything in the screenshot in order to edit the content of a homepage.

Also, I am not sure which theme are we using in wordpress here. Is there any, we can know that ? In the appearance themes section, I found this(not sure which theme I am using):

[image]

Comment: Well it says "Active: CAUBO". That's the theme. Since it has the same name as your site, someone must have custom developed it for you. You'll need to ask whoever did that what to do. If they're not available then you'll probably have to hire someone who knows code to be able to investigate and tell you. No one here's going to be able to tell you how to work with a completely custom theme.

Comment: @JacobPeattie That's answer my question I guess that we are using custom theme. Thanks for that.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572821/how-to-make-both-up-down-arrow-in-select-input-field-in-css?noredirect=1#comment92082171_52572821). i am wondering if you can give me some pointer.

Comment: That isn’t remotely similar...

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yeah, I agree that isn't remotely similar but it is from the same website. Any word on that ?

Answer (score 1):

There are various sites that will tell you the theme and plugins used on any site. One is https://whatwpthemeisthat.com/ , there are many others.

In general, what you see when you login to the admin area depends on your user level. Admins see everything, guests see only their own profile. So it may be that your user is not an 'admin' level of privilege. Your question didn't specify your user level.

It may also be that a plugin is restricting what you see. So you could use the above site (or similar) to see if there is a plugin installed that is limiting your access. You would have to look at the info on the plugins (via the plugin's page) to see if there is something that is limiting your access.

A theme could limit what you see after logging in, but I would think that is less likely.

But, I suspect, given the limited information you provided, that you are not an admin-level user. So that would limit what you can see.

If you are using an admin-level account, then you will need to provide more info: your user privilege level, plugins installed, and theme used.

Comment: Yes, I am using an admin level account. How can I know which theme am I using ? Is there any we can know that ?

Comment: I have updated my question. You will find more information which theme I am using.

Comment: I think, its not a theme from wordpress. It is something else (not sure).

Comment: After you login, the URL should be www.example.com/wp-admin . Is that where you are as shown in the first screenshot in your question? What happens if you click the up-triangle in that screenshot?  If this is a test site, rename your plugins folder to something else (to disable them all) and log in again. If that doesn't give you a normal admin screen, rename the active theme ("CAUBO") folder (in wp-content/themes) to get back to a default WP theme.